# Solve the differential equation $ y'' + y' + 1 = 2\cos x + \sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What type is this equation $ y'' + y' + 1 = 2\cos x + \sin x$? That "$1$" confuses me.

Comment: This is $y'' + y' = 2\cos x + \sin x-1$. Better looking?

Comment: Moral: never let a "1" to confuse you!

Comment: However: this is a second order linear non-homogeneous ordinary differential equation. This can easily solved, for example,  in two steps as a sequence of  two first order differential equations according to the hint of user1892304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

Let put

$z=y'+1$.

the equation becomes
$$z'+z=\sqrt{5}\sin(x+\alpha)$$

with $\alpha\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and

$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$.

the solution without RHS is

$z_h=Ce^{-x}$

a particular solution $z_p$ can be found as $z_p=C(x)e^{-x}$ where

$$C(x)=\sqrt{5} \int \sin(x+\alpha)e^x dx $$ is obtained after two by parts integrations.

and the final solution is

$$y=\int (z_h+z_p)dx -x +D$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** substitute $u=y'$ and you obtain a first-order linear differential equation in $u$ which can be solved using an integrating factor.